# Weird console printing

Tags: c#

I wanted to animate text appearing in console and suceed, but when I tried to write text from different coordinates it still appears from (0,0) for some reason. I can't figure out why.

```
const string logo = @"                       __              ____  __ __    ______   __             
           __         /\ \__          /'___\/\ \\ \  /\  ___\ /\ \            
  ___ ___ /\_\    ____\ \ ,_\  __  __/\ \__/\ \ \\ \ \ \ \__/ \ \/      ____  
/' __` __`\/\ \  /',__\\ \ \/ /\ \/\ \ \  _``\ \ \\ \_\ \___``\\/      /',__\ 
/\ \/\ \/\ \ \ \/\__, `\\ \ \_\ \ \_\ \ \ \L\ \ \__ ,__\/\ \L\ \      /\__, `\
\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_\/\____/ \ \__\\/`____ \ \____/\/_/\_\_/\ \____/      \/\____/
 \/_/\/_/\/_/\/_/\/___/   \/__/ `/___/> \/___/    \/_/   \/___/        \/___/ 
                                   /\___/                                     
                                   \/__/                                      ";


char[,] logoArray = new char[9, 79];

char[] logoCharArray = logo.ToCharArray();

int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 79; j++)
    {
        logoArray[i, j] = logoCharArray[counter];
        counter++;
    }
}


AnimatedArray();

void AnimatedArray()
{
    for (int i = 0, from = 9, num = 1; i < 9; i++, from--, num++)
    {
        System.Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        PrintArrayLines(logoArray, from, num);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

void PrintArrayLine(char[,] array, int arrayLine)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 79; i++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(array[arrayLine - 1, i]);
    }
}

void PrintArrayLines(char[,] array, int startFrom, int linesQuantity)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < linesQuantity; i++)
    {
        PrintArrayLine(array, startFrom);
        startFrom++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);` - what do you mean by "different coordinates"?

Comment: @GuruStron If I try to print array from other coordinates different from (0,0) it don't work. Changing SetCursorPosition in AnimatedArray doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Please show the example.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you copy the array from 1D to 2D? You could just compute the respective index or use a 2D Array in the first place?

Comment: @GuruStron What example can I provide?

Comment: @Fildor I have a string which I want to become a 2 dimensional array. That was the only way I imagined to get such a result.

Comment: Are newlines _in_ the data? If so: it doesn't suffice to set the initial cursor position. If you have a newline, that's a crlf as in "carriage return, line feed" so, x goes back to 0. If you want to translate the whole thing, set cursor position for each line.

Comment: @Fildor You mean there are some WriteLine()-like symbols in that string I converted into the array?

Comment: That's what I am asking, yes. And regarding array dimensions: if you already have a 1D Array, that represents 2D Data, you can "emulate" 2D Api, that just maps (x|y) coords to a 1D index. Like Index = f (x,y) = y*width + x , for example.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would try to split the logo by new line and move the offset when printing every line instead of managing every single character:

```
const string logo = ...;
const int offset = 15;

var strings = logo.Split(Environment.NewLine);

AnimatedArray();

void AnimatedArray()
{
    for (int i = 0, from = 9, num = 1; i < 9; i++, from--, num++)
    {
        System.Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        PrintArrayLines(from, num);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

void PrintArrayLine(int arrayLine)
{
    System.Console.SetCursorPosition(offset, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.WriteLine(strings[arrayLine - 1]);
}

void PrintArrayLines(int startFrom, int linesQuantity)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < linesQuantity; i++)
    {
        PrintArrayLine(startFrom);
        startFrom++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Split method don't accept Environment.NewLine parameter. "Can't convert from string to chat".

Comment: @coldheart it depends on framework version you are using, try changing it to `.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine})`

Comment: Still don't work.

Comment: @coldheart how exactly it does not work?

Comment: It still don't accept parameter with the same reason.

Comment: @coldheart check out the available methods and parameters - `.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)` .

Comment: Even splitted to strings I still have to deal with CRLF. That's the reason for setting offset for every single line, I guess?

Comment: @coldheart there are options to handle that too. Actually you can just change your code to create strings from arrays of 79 chars (via `new string(charArray)`).